# how to solve cyclic-dependency & Iterator lifetime problem?

Tags: rust, lifetime, cyclic-dependency

Rustaceans. when I start to write a BloomFilter example in rust. I found I have serveral problems have to solve. I struggle to solve them but no progress in a day. I need help, any suggestion will help me a lot, Thanks.

### Problems

1. <s>How to solve lifetime when pass a Iterator into another function?</s>

```rust
// let bits = self.hash(value); // how to solve such lifetime error without use 'static storage?
 
// Below is a workaround code but need to computed in advanced.
let bits = Box::new(self.hash(value).collect::<Vec<u64>>().into_iter());
self.0.set(bits);
```

2. <s>How to solve cyclic-dependency between struts without modify lower layer code, e.g: `bloom_filter` ?</s>

```rust
// cyclic-dependency:
// RedisCache -> BloomFilter -> Storage
//    |                            ^
//    ------------<impl>------------
//
//                                     v--- cache ownership has moved here
let filter = BloomFilter::by(Box::new(cache));
cache.1.replace(filter);
```

3. <s>Since rust does not have `null` value, How can I solve the cyclic-dependency initialization without any stubs?</s>

```rust
let mut cache = RedisCache(
    Client::open("redis://localhost").unwrap(),
    // I found can use Weak::new() to solve it,but need to downgrade a Rc reference.
    //                    v-- need a BloomFilter stub to create RedisCache
    RefCell::new(BloomFilter::new()),
);
```

### Code

```rust
#![allow(unused)]

mod bloom_filter {
    use std::{hash::Hash, marker::PhantomData};

    pub type BitsIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u64>>;

    pub trait Storage {
        fn set(&mut self, bits: BitsIter);

        fn contains_all(&self, bits: BitsIter) -> bool;
    }

    pub struct BloomFilter<T: Hash>(Box<dyn Storage>, PhantomData<T>);

    impl<T: Hash> BloomFilter<T> {
        pub fn new() -> BloomFilter<T> {
            return Self::by(Box::new(ArrayStorage([0; 5000])));

            struct ArrayStorage<const N: usize>([u8; N]);

            impl<const N: usize> Storage for ArrayStorage<N> {
                fn set(&mut self, bits: BitsIter) {
                    let size = self.0.len() as u64;
                    bits.map(|bit| (bit % size) as usize)
                        .for_each(|index| self.0[index] = 1);
                }

                fn contains_all(&self, bits: BitsIter) -> bool {
                    let size = self.0.len() as u64;
                    bits.map(|bit| (bit % size) as usize)
                        .all(|index| self.0[index] == 1)
                }
            }
        }

        pub fn by(storage: Box<dyn Storage>) -> BloomFilter<T> {
            BloomFilter(storage, PhantomData)
        }

        pub fn add(&mut self, value: T) {
            // let bits = self.hash(value); // how to solve such lifetime error?
            let bits = Box::new(self.hash(value).collect::<Vec<u64>>().into_iter());
            self.0.set(bits);
        }

        pub fn contains(&self, value: T) -> bool {
            // lifetime problem same as Self::add(T)
            let bits = Box::new(self.hash(value).collect::<Vec<u64>>().into_iter());
            self.0.contains_all(bits)
        }

        fn hash<'a, H: Hash + 'a>(&self, _value: H) -> Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u64> + 'a> {
            todo!()
        }
    }
}

mod spi {
    use super::bloom_filter::*;
    use redis::{Client, Commands, RedisResult};
    use std::{
        cell::RefCell,
        rc::{Rc, Weak},
    };

    pub struct RedisCache<'a>(Client, RefCell<BloomFilter<&'a str>>);

    impl<'a> RedisCache<'a> {
        pub fn new() -> RedisCache<'a> {
            let mut cache = RedisCache(
                Client::open("redis://localhost").unwrap(),
                //                    v-- need a BloomFilter stub to create RedisCache
                RefCell::new(BloomFilter::new()),
            );
            //                                      v--- cache ownership has moved here
            let filter = BloomFilter::by(Box::new(cache));
            cache.1.replace(filter);
            return cache;
        }

        pub fn get(&mut self, key: &str, load_value: fn() -> Option<String>) -> Option<String> {
            let filter = self.1.borrow();
            if filter.contains(key) {
                if let Ok(value) = self.0.get::<&str, String>(key) {
                    return Some(value);
                }
                if let Some(actual_value) = load_value() {
                    let _: () = self.0.set(key, &actual_value).unwrap();
                    return Some(actual_value);
                }
            }
            return None;
        }
    }

    impl<'a> Storage for RedisCache<'a> {
        fn set(&mut self, bits: BitsIter) {
            todo!()
        }

        fn contains_all(&self, bits: BitsIter) -> bool {
            todo!()
        }
    }
}
```

### Updated

---

First, thanks [@Colonel Thirty Two](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646619/colonel-thirty-two) give me a lot of information that I haven't mastered and help me fixed the problem of the iterator lifetime.
The cyclic-dependency I have solved by break the responsibility of the `Storage` into another struct `RedisStorage` without modify the `bloom_filter` module, but make the example bloated. Below is their relationships:

```rust
RedisCache ->  BloomFilter  -> Storage  <---------------
    |                                                  |
    |-------> redis::Client <- RedisStorage ---<impl>---
```

I realized the ownership & lifetime system is not only used by borrow checker, but also Rustaceans need a bigger front design to obey the rules than in a GC language, e.g: java. Am I right?

### Final Code

```rust
mod bloom_filter {
    use std::{
        hash::{Hash, Hasher},
        marker::PhantomData,
    };

    pub type BitsIter<'a> = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u64> + 'a>;

    pub trait Storage {
        fn set(&mut self, bits: BitsIter);

        fn contains_all(&self, bits: BitsIter) -> bool;
    }

    pub struct BloomFilter<T: Hash>(Box<dyn Storage>, PhantomData<T>);

    impl<T: Hash> BloomFilter<T> {
        #[allow(unused)]
        pub fn new() -> BloomFilter<T> {
            return Self::by(Box::new(ArrayStorage([0; 5000])));

            struct ArrayStorage<const N: usize>([u8; N]);

            impl<const N: usize> Storage for ArrayStorage<N> {
                fn set(&mut self, bits: BitsIter) {
                    let size = self.0.len() as u64;
                    bits.map(|bit| (bit % size) as usize)
                        .for_each(|index| self.0[index] = 1);
                }

                fn contains_all(&self, bits: BitsIter) -> bool {
                    let size = self.0.len() as u64;
                    bits.map(|bit| (bit % size) as usize)
                        .all(|index| self.0[index] == 1)
                }
            }
        }

        pub fn by(storage: Box<dyn Storage>) -> BloomFilter<T> {
            BloomFilter(storage, PhantomData)
        }

        pub fn add(&mut self, value: T) {
            self.0.set(self.hash(value));
        }

        pub fn contains(&self, value: T) -> bool {
            self.0.contains_all(self.hash(value))
        }

        fn hash<'a, H: Hash + 'a>(&self, value: H) -> BitsIter<'a> {
            Box::new(
                [3, 11, 31, 71, 131]
                    .into_iter()
                    .map(|salt| SimpleHasher(0, salt))
                    .map(move |mut hasher| hasher.hash(&value)),
            )
        }
    }
    struct SimpleHasher(u64, u64);

    impl SimpleHasher {
        fn hash<H: Hash>(&mut self, value: &H) -> u64 {
            value.hash(self);
            self.finish()
        }
    }

    impl Hasher for SimpleHasher {
        fn finish(&self) -> u64 {
            self.0
        }

        fn write(&mut self, bytes: &[u8]) {
            self.0 += bytes.iter().fold(0u64, |acc, k| acc * self.1 + *k as u64)
        }
    }
}

mod spi {
    use super::bloom_filter::*;
    use redis::{Client, Commands};
    use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

    pub struct RedisCache<'a>(Rc<RefCell<Client>>, BloomFilter<&'a str>);

    impl<'a> RedisCache<'a> {
        pub fn new(client: Rc<RefCell<Client>>, filter: BloomFilter<&'a str>) -> RedisCache<'a> {
            RedisCache(client, filter)
        }

        pub fn get<'f>(
            &mut self,
            key: &str,
            load_value: fn() -> Option<&'f str>,
        ) -> Option<String> {
            if self.1.contains(key) {
                let mut redis = self.0.as_ref().borrow_mut();
                if let Ok(value) = redis.get::<&str, String>(key) {
                    return Some(value);
                }
                if let Some(actual_value) = load_value() {
                    let _: () = redis.set(key, &actual_value).unwrap();
                    return Some(actual_value.into());
                }
            }
            return None;
        }
    }

    struct RedisStorage(Rc<RefCell<Client>>);

    const BLOOM_FILTER_KEY: &str = "bloom_filter";
    impl Storage for RedisStorage {
        fn set(&mut self, bits: BitsIter) {
            bits.for_each(|slot| {
                let _: bool = self
                    .0
                    .as_ref()
                    .borrow_mut()
                    .setbit(BLOOM_FILTER_KEY, slot as usize, true)
                    .unwrap();
            })
        }

        fn contains_all(&self, mut bits: BitsIter) -> bool {
            bits.all(|slot| {
                self.0
                    .as_ref()
                    .borrow_mut()
                    .getbit(BLOOM_FILTER_KEY, slot as usize)
                    .unwrap()
            })
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn prevent_cache_penetration_by_bloom_filter() {
        let client = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Client::open("redis://localhost").unwrap()));
        redis::cmd("FLUSHDB").execute(&mut *client.as_ref().borrow_mut());
        let mut filter: BloomFilter<&str> = BloomFilter::by(Box::new(RedisStorage(client.clone())));

        assert!(!filter.contains("Rust"));

        filter.add("Rust");
        assert!(filter.contains("Rust"));

        let mut cache = RedisCache::new(client, filter);

        assert_eq!(
            cache.get("Rust", || Some("System Language")),
            Some("System Language".to_string())
        );
        assert_eq!(
            cache.get("Rust", || panic!("must never be called after cached")),
            Some("System Language".to_string())
        );
        assert_eq!(
            cache.get("Go", || panic!("reject to loading `Go` from external storage")),
            None
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> pub type BitsIter = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u64>>;

In this case, the object in the box must be valid for the `'static` lifetime. This isn't the case for the iterator returned by `hash` - its limited to the lifetime of `self`.

Try replacing with:

```
pub type BitsIter<'a> = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = u64> + 'a>;
```

Or using generics instead of boxed trait objects.

---

So your `RedisClient` needs a `BloomFilter`, but the `BloomFilter` also needs the `RedisClient`?

Your `BloomFilter` should not use the `RedisCache` that itself uses the `BloomFilter` - that's a recipe for infinitely recursing calls (how do you know what calls to `RedisCache::add` should update the bloom filter and which calls are from the bloom filter?).

If you really have to, you need some form of shared ownership, like `Rc` or `Arc`. Your `BloomFilter` will also need to use a weak reference, or else the two objects will refer to each other and will never free.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot. I have tried your suggestion to using generics instead of boxed trait objects, but the compiler complain lifetime problem  again, -_-. Could you help me again. I come from a GC language with a little knowledge of ownership & lifetime, I found the official website doesn't have enough resources about them. Did you have any resources about them?